# How can the logs be turned off on Apache Spark 3+?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have successfully installed pyspark and the "pyspark" command launches the spark shell. Though whenever I use "spark-submit" as a command, a ton of logging messages appear. I have tried every solution on other questions yet none of them works. My file is named "log4j2.templates" and its structured in the following way:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = console
```

Whenever i try setting it to ERROR/error or even setting it inside the code still features those logs. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following properties, it will force the logger to set level error to any log comming from org.apache.spark:

```
logger.spark.name = org.apache.spark
logger.spark.level = error
```

Note that if logs are comming from a third party, this will not work on the logs comming from the third party.

Comment: I believe this only controls logs from the driver, not the executors